# How to connect 2 different computers on a network using a chat application in Java?

Tags: java

I have a simple pair of client and server programs. Client connects to server and when it does connect, the server replies with a "Hello there" message. How should I modify the program if I want the client and server programs to run on different systems?

Here is the code for the client side..

```
package practice;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DailyAdviceClient
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DailyAdviceClient dac = new DailyAdviceClient();
        dac.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        try
        {
            Socket incoming = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4242);
            InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream);
            String advice = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();
            System.out.println("Today's advice is "+advice);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Client Side Error");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the server

```
package practice;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DailyAdviceServer
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DailyAdviceServer das = new DailyAdviceServer();
        das.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serversock = new ServerSocket(4242);

            while(true)
            {
                Socket outgoing = serversock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outgoing.getOutputStream());
                writer.println("Hello there");
                writer.close();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Server Side Problem");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By systems, do you mean you want them to connect to one another over more than one LAN?

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to input the correct IP address?  Also you'd have to ensure the port you use is open on the routers you are using.

Comment: Hint: You might want to add a `outgoing.close()` after closing your writer, since the socket isn't going to be used again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change "127.0.0.1" on the client with the server's IP and make sure the port 4242 is open.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Socket incoming = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4242);
```

This is creating a socket listening to the server at the address `127.0.0.1` on port `4242`. If you change the server to another address, for example of a different pc, then change the ip address that your socket is listening to.

It is also worth noting that you will probably have to open up or allow access to the ports you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Client requires ip address and port of server, means ip of that system which you making server and port (4242).so in client you need to change

```
Socket incoming = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4242); BY 
Socket incoming = new Socket("IP address of server",4242);
```

And make sure both system is connected via wired or wireless network.